# Using rails-jquery-autocomplete on varying model/controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I am using the rails-jquery-autocomplete gem for my Rails project with normal form helpers with one model's data on several controllers/views. Like let's say I have a comments model and use comments at many occasions.

In this particular case I am using several forms in an admin namespace. With normal select fields I have a working solution, but as you can imagine, the options to select from will grow by time and I don't want to have a select field with hundreds of results. Hence I want it to become an autocomplete textfield instead. But I don't know how to access the correct data.

In my example I am using a form for a `@gallery` on a foreign admins controller. In the form right now I let editors chose which `@game` belongs to a `@gallery`. Like so:

```
<%= form_for(@gallery) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.select :game_id, options_for_select(@games.map {|g| [g.name, g.id]}) %>
...
<% end %>
```

If I use

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_name_games_path %>
```

instead it tells me, that `:name` is not available with my `@gallery` object, which is true, in so far I added `autocomplete :name` to the games controller as it should be populated with data from it.
But I thought I could use the autocomplete of the games controller's `:name` at the admin controller's form, too.

When I try to use it with `:game_id` like

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :game_id, autocomplete_name_games_path %>
```

then it tells me that the id is missing, I added the `:id_element => '#some_element'` with the correct value of a hidden field I added. I checked the source code and the hidden field is there but this does not change the error message on this autocomplete gem.

Perhaps someone could tell me, how I can access the data with the rails-jquery-autocomplete gem on a foreign controller's view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out several things by trial and error and can now use this plugin as I intended to. As such I want to provide an answer. Maybe someone else could use it, at least someone voted my question up...

1. You can add the `autocomplete` method to **every** controller you want, for every model you want. At first I thought I had to use it on the particular controller I want the results from, because the examples in the plugin's readme tend to propose this by coincidence. So using:

   ```
   class AdminController < ApplicationController
   ...
   autocomplete :game, :name
   ```

   within my AdminController (or every other one) would result in a possibility to search/autocomplete the game model's data by name.
2. Then the readme on the plugin describes very vaguely what to do and how the `:id_element => '#some_element'` has to be used or what it resembles (cf. https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete#getting-the-object-id). I thought that I had to add an id field and output the corresponding id of my selection by myself. This is **not** necessary. The object id of the `autocomplete` element is always there but not directly output within the html, only on selection.
   Instead one has to change the value of the normal id every form element has. In one of my examples the form field's id was: `id="image_game_id"`. Hence I had to use it like follows:

   ```
   <%= f.autocomplete_field :game_id, admin_autocomplete_game_name_path, :id_element => '#image_game_id' %>
   ```
3. The only thing I don't yet know is, how to show the name instead of the ID in the form field, when selected. I will edit my answer, as soon as I get to know how to do this. That is, when it's possible.